# ModalBottomSheet crashes when device is rotated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I use a **ModalBottomSheet** from Material3 to contain a LazyVerticalGrid which contains some items. However, when I rotate the device, the app crashes and the following error is shown:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The offset was read before being initialized. Did you access the offset in a phase before layout, like effects or composition?
```

This is the full code:

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
val colors = List(21) { Color.Blue }

ModalBottomSheet(
    modifier = Modifier.widthIn(max = 450.dp),
    onDismissRequest = {},
    sheetState = bottomSheetState
) {
    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(7),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp),
    ) {
        items(colors) { color ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(color = color)
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

When 14 colors are used instead of 21, the crash does not occur. Also, it is probably not an issue with `LazyVerticalGrid` because the following alternative way of displaying a grid using a Column with a fixed Circle size causes the crash as well:

```
val numRows = 3
val numCols = 7
val circleSize = 48.dp
val circleSpacing = 8.dp

...
Column() {    // In place of the LazyVerticalGrid
    for (row in 0 until numRows) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
        ) {
            for (col in 0 until numCols) {
                val colorIndex = row * numCols + col
                if (colorIndex < colors.size) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(circleSize)
                            .background(colors[colorIndex], shape = CircleShape)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(circleSpacing))
    }
}
...
```

Could this be an API issue because ModalBottomSheet is still experimental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved in `material3:1.2.0-alpha07`.

You can use these versions.

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha07"
```

or

```
 implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha09"
```